# Calculate the growth of deltas in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is there a way to calculate the growth per year of deltas in database?

I would like to know if my current server is enough or should I switch to bigger server and required to check the growth over the years, is it doable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of posts on the Internet with various solutions for this.  A quick search of '**Sql Server Track Database Growth**' found [this one](https://sqljourney.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/sql-server-track-database-size-growth-trend/) at the very top.  I haven't vetted it, so due diligence applies.  To summarize:

First create a table to keep the size information of each database with a date on which the information is collected:

```
CREATE TABLE DatabaseFileSize
(
[database_id] INT,
[file_id] INT,
[file_type_desc] NVARCHAR(120),
[name] NVARCHAR(128),
[physical_name] NVARCHAR(520),
[state_desc] NVARCHAR(120),
[size] INT,
[max_size] INT,
[growth] INT,
[is_sparse] BIT,
[is_percent_growth] BIT,
[collect_date] DATETIME
)
GO
```

Create a stored procedure to populate this table with the current database size information:

```
CREATE PROC usp_util_CollectDatabaseSize
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
INSERT INTO DatabaseFileSize
(
[database_id],
[file_id],
[file_type_desc],
[name],
[physical_name],
[state_desc],
[size],
[max_size],
[growth],
[is_sparse],
[is_percent_growth],
[collect_date]
)
SELECT
[database_id],
[file_id],
[type_desc],
[name],
[physical_name],
[state_desc],
[size],
[max_size],
[growth],
[is_sparse],
[is_percent_growth],
GETDATE()
FROM sys.master_files
SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
GO
```

Now we need to populate the table over a period of time, so we need to create a SQL Agent job to execute this stored procedure and schedule this job to run everyday.

```
USE [msdb]
GO
/****** Object:  Job [Collect_Database_Size_Info]    Script Date: 02/13/2013 23:47:43 ******/
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @ReturnCode INT
SELECT @ReturnCode = 0
/****** Object:  JobCategory [[Uncategorized (Local)]]]    Script Date: 02/13/2013 23:47:43 ******/
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.syscategories WHERE name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]' AND category_class=1)
BEGIN
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_category @class=N'JOB', @type=N'LOCAL', @name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
END
DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'Collect_Database_Size_Info',
@enabled=1,
@notify_level_eventlog=0,
@notify_level_email=0,
@notify_level_netsend=0,
@notify_level_page=0,
@delete_level=0,
@description=N'No description available.',
@category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]',
@owner_login_name=N'Domain\User', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
/****** Object:  Step [DBSize]    Script Date: 02/13/2013 23:47:44 ******/
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'DBSize',
@step_id=1,
@cmdexec_success_code=0,
@on_success_action=1,
@on_success_step_id=0,
@on_fail_action=2,
@on_fail_step_id=0,
@retry_attempts=0,
@retry_interval=0,
@os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL',
@command=N'EXEC usp_util_CollectDatabaseSize',
@database_name=N'AuditDB',
@flags=0
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id = @jobId, @start_step_id = 1
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule @job_id=@jobId, @name=N'DailyDBSize',
@enabled=1,
@freq_type=4,
@freq_interval=1,
@freq_subday_type=1,
@freq_subday_interval=0,
@freq_relative_interval=0,
@freq_recurrence_factor=0,
@active_start_date=20130213,
@active_end_date=99991231,
@active_start_time=0,
@active_end_time=235959,
@schedule_uid=N'445fb175-517b-4221-b6b8-6c6877dc7c24'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @jobId, @server_name = N'(local)'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
COMMIT TRANSACTION
GOTO EndSave
QuitWithRollback:
IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
EndSave:

GO
```

Now we have the information over the period of time and we can run our below query to make a report out of this data.

```
--DB Size Growth Trend
SELECT
DB_NAME(database_id) AS DatabaseName,
collect_date AS CollectionDate,
((SUM(size))*8)/1024 AS DBSizeInMB
FROM DatabaseFileSize
GROUP BY database_id,collect_date
ORDER BY DatabaseName,collect_date

--DB File Size Growth Trend
SELECT DB_NAME(database_id) AS DatabaseName,
(CASE file_type_desc
WHEN 'ROWS' THEN 'Data'
WHEN 'LOG' THEN 'Log'
END) AS FileType,
physical_name AS PhysicalPath,
collect_date AS CollectionDate,
((SUM(size))*8)/1024 AS FileSizeInMB
FROM DatabaseFileSize
GROUP BY database_id,physical_name,file_type_desc,collect_date
ORDER BY DatabaseName,collect_date
```

If you want to look back in time for database growth, you can use the information in Erin Stellato's blog post [Trending Database Growth From Backups](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/erin/trending-database-growth-from-backups/)

This technique relies on information in msdb.dbo.backupset which is pruned by various maintenance plans and possibly other processes, so you may only be able to go back a few months. Here's the main query from that post:

```
SELECT
[database_name] AS "Database",
DATEPART(month,[backup_start_date]) AS "Month",
AVG([backup_size]/1024/1024) AS "Backup Size MB",
AVG([compressed_backup_size]/1024/1024) AS "Compressed Backup Size MB",
AVG([backup_size]/[compressed_backup_size]) AS "Compression Ratio"
FROM msdb.dbo.backupset
WHERE [database_name] = N'AdventureWorks'
AND [type] = 'D'
GROUP BY [database_name],DATEPART(mm,[backup_start_date]);
```

Comment: This is good from now, but what I need to know is the growth trend from 2 years until now.

Comment: You may be able to look back in time by running queries against msdb.dbo.backupset. I've updated my answer regarding this.